# Unable to start gunicorn(Django Node app) on heroku Error : Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 46831)

Tags: django, node.js, heroku, django-urls, gunicorn

I am trying to host a Django Node app on heroku. And my procfile looks like this

```
web: gunicorn backend courier.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT & node frontend/server.js
```

My server.js runs the index.html. And my is showing the index.html page. But the Django urls do not work.

And my heroku logs show this.

```
    2016-02-28T17:25:40.032724+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-02-28 17:25:40 +0000] [7] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
    2016-02-28T17:25:40.258117+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2016-02-28T17:25:41.042335+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-02-28 17:25:41 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 46831)
    2016-02-28T17:25:41.042419+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-02-28 17:25:41 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
```

And my gunicorni doesn't start.

However, when i remove `& node frontend/server.js` from my procfile it runs the django app normally and all my Django URLs work.

Would be great if somebody could tell me what is wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that you start node and django on the same port.

Comment: I dont think i can control the port numbers on heroku. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Check [that](https://engineering.heroku.com/blogs/2014-10-29-heroku-django-node/)

Comment: Why do you want to run both Django and Node?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I am using node in the frontend and Django in the backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can have two ports for two different processes on a single heroku  dyno.

You might have to use another dyno to run the other.

Also I suggest putting the frontend pages as static files and serving them through Django.